# D3 - attribute d: Expected number Error in creating curved chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, linechart

I am trying to create a D3 chart which has time of the day 24-hour notation on x-axis and corresponding values on Y-axis with a smooth curve.

This is my code and it gives an error - 
`Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,450LNaN,450C…".`

I have put my code in fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/x200v7mq/2/

Comment: Can someone explain why the question is downgraded?

Comment: @Cyril: Can you edit the fiddle to make it work and post it as an answer? It will be of great help.

Comment: That doesn't look like the case. If the comment out `x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
     return d.p;
 }));`, the axis comes fine. Its only the values which are not plotting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to parse your strings:

```
var timeFormat = d3.time.format("%H:%M");

data.forEach(function(d){
    d.p = timeFormat.parse(d.p);
});
```

Here is your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rp0ws88k/

Comment: Superb! Thanks a lot.